# Some Android devices don't find the resources when debugging with Android Studio

Tags: android

When I open the app in some devices (with android 5.0.3), the app crashes and the log cat shows that error:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0c009f
```

I have read in some other stackoverflow posts that maybe it could be happening because of Android Studio, and I edited the Gradle, adding this code inside "android" section, to determine which is the Resources folder:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
                res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets']
            }
        }
}
```

How can I do that all the devices find the Resources?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and building again? I think the most likely thing is you've changed some resources but the R.java file wasn't regenerated properly.

Comment: @Karakuri  It was the first I tried, but it's not the solution. Thanks